# Sort list by String attribute with Java 8

Tags: java, sorting

I have a list of users and they have `status` as attribute and I want 
the users who have status 'disable' be at the end of the list. There are 4 types of status: 'disable', 'connect', 'notConnect', 'deleted'.

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Comment: `List<User> users = list.stream().filter(user -> !user.getStatus().equals("disable")).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Nikolas that's gonna give a list with only not disable users, not a list with disabled user at the end of it. ;) This required an ordered list on the status (everything that is not `disable` as a lower "value" that `disable` itself)

Comment: you can use priority queue and sort by status

Comment: Use `Collection.sort(Comparator)` and `Comparator.comparing(...`. If you get stuck, give us more detail. There are quite some questions here on this site that show how to write Comparators.

Comment: Not super efficient but `List<String> sortOrder = Arrays.asList("connect", "notConnect", "deleted", "disable"); users.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(user -> sortOrder.indexOf(user.status)));` gives you complete control over the order. Anything not in the list is ordered before the things in the list

Comment: @zapl thank your code resolve my probleme thanks and thanks for all comments

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the list using a `Comparator` that evaluates `"disable"` as larger than any other status.

```
users.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(user -> "disable".equals(user.status) ? 1 : 0));
```

You can extend this solution by adding integer rankings for the other statuses as well.

Comment: a `Boolean` is `Comparable` so you're not required to use ints, hence the above could aswell be simplified to `users.sort(Comparator.comparing(user -> "disable".equals(user.status)));` but still this breaks the Comparator contract. you can instead do `users.sort(Comparator.comparing((User u) -> "disable".equals(u.status)).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));`